# PyPDF2 Extract rectangles and texts into a SVG-file

Tags: pypdf

in the  below example from PyPDF2 documentation:

[image: Example2]

How to understand the code from: `if op == b"re"` to the end?

Which resources can I study to understand it?

Comment: PyPDF2 is deprecated. Use pypdf.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the operand b"re" means that we want to extract a rectangle (from "re").

So the sentence if op==b"re" may means that it extract all text that are contained in a rectangle.

You should test this code and see how it works, which specific text is extracted from the pdf.

Comment: what about the next line: (x, y, w, h) = (args[i].as_numeric() for i in range(4)), 
what args[i], 
how to know the arguments of def visitor_svg_rect(op, args, cm, tm): and def visitor_svg_text(text, cm, tm, fontDict, fontSize):

Answer (score 0):

This is not an easy topic because Python is shielding you from the underlying tasks

What a PDF looks like in term of surface appearance (centre) so its uppermost structure in order is seen on the left.

However the real PDF is binary bits and bytes which when decoded into ANSI looks like the text on the right, and this is what the library is visiting.

Our current focus is `70.584 48.36 470.95 0.47998 re` which is the third significant rectangle at bottom of page, and often a page object near its start may be described before others higher up.

PDF can be written in any order so pages themselves can be found in random order, we index to show in a sequence. Here we are on 3 and 4 and 5 are now shown to the right.

[image]

So the authors PDF writer of that PDF decided to draw a rectangle for a horizontal rule and that is not uncommon but exceptionally wasteful of a description and confusing for conversion into a SVG equivalence, since a move and a single line would have done it faster. Also note the re[ctangle] above our focus (`0.00125 -0.12134 612.09 792.12 re`) is the 2nd of 2 very similar and **almost** equal the page boundary `MediaBox[0 0 612 792]` but not quite perfectly.

Q) what is

```
def visitor_svg_rect(op, args, cm, tm):
    if op == b"re":
        (x, y, w, h) = (args[i].as_numeric() for i in range(4))
        dwg.add(dwg.rect((x, y), (w, h), stroke="red", fill_opacity=0.05))
```

doing and how to understand why.

A) Much is down to trial, error and experience since no 2 PDFs are written or behave the same.

My understanding of the function is it searches for the "re" then gathers
the prior 4 values and then combines those with other it collected (cm and tm) to rewrite that area something like edge it in redish rust ?

I will cheat and let my non python editor rewrite as

```
q
0 0 0 rg .5 0 0 RG .5 w .001 -0.121 612.09 792.12 re W* n
70.584 48.36 470.95 .48 re B*
Q
```

But you would need to look at before after and the PyPDF SVG output to see what it does.

By combining multiple functions such as only look for text and then write a fresh blue and red rectangle around the text (`visitor_operand_before=visitor_svg_rect, visitor_text=visitor_svg_text`) we can start to generate PDF primitives that emulate the native permanent highlights that annotations would do.